# Column [key] throws MissingPrimaryKeyException in dataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

```
        var sdr = db.ExecuteReader("SELECT [key],translation FROM language WHERE lang=@lang");
        DataTable someTable = new DataTable();
        someTable.Load(sdr);
        return ((string)(someTable.Rows.Find("[key] = CUSTOMDATEFORMAT").ItemArray[1]));
```

The last line now throws the error `System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException`: "The table has no primary key."

So I guess it finds the keyword "key" and now expects me to query on the primary key column, not the column named "key". How do I have to escape the column name?

Comment: If you use `Find` you have to specify the [primary key(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [`DataRowCollection.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk(v=vs.110).aspx) you have to specify the `DataTable`'s [`PrimaryKey`(s)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I would use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
DataRow row = someTable.AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Field<string>("key") == "CUSTOMDATEFORMAT");
if(row != null)
    return row.Field<string>(1); // or by name but with correct type
else 
    return "something else";
```

Then you can use all methods you want in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.find.aspx) method is used to find a single rows by the primary key value.  Use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) to find rows by arbitrary column values:

```
DataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = someTable.Select("[key] = CUSTOMDATEFORMAT");
return foundRows[0].ItemArray[1];  // adding proper bounds checking, of course.
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk(v=vs.110).aspx) method is using the column that is specified in the `DataTable` object as `primary key` and return a row that contains the value it gets inside the `primary key` cell.
From MSDN:

> Gets the row specified by the primary key value.

Since your table doesn't have a column that is specified as a `primary key`, you get this error.

If your `key` column is guaranteed to not contain duplicates, you can specify it as the primary key using the [`DataTable`'s `PrimaryKey` property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey(v=vs.110).aspx)

If not, then use Linq's `Select` method instead of find:

```
return ((string)(someTable.Rows.Select("[key] = CUSTOMDATEFORMAT").ItemArray[1]));
```